# Correct way to initialize a 2D struct char array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

The extra Q at the end of rotor[0][0].order is from rotor[0][0].notch. What is the cause of this and what should be done to avoid this concatenation?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct rotor_wirings
{
    char order[26];
    char notch[2];
};
/* rotor[MODEL][ROTORNAME] */
struct rotor_wirings rotor[10][10] =
{
    /* Commercial Enigma A, B */
    {
        { "DMTWSILRUYQNKFEJCAZBPGXOHV", "Q" },
        { "HQZGPJTMOBLNCIFDYAWVEUSRKX", "E" }
    }
};

int main()
{
    printf("First rotor is: %s\n", rotor[0][0].order);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
First rotor is: DMTWSILRUYQNKFEJCAZBPGXOHVQ
```

Comment: You are crossing the limit. It is UB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Note that the undefined behaviour is in the `printf()` line, not in the initialization. You have reserved 26 bytes to store 26 characters; the data is not null terminated. That's valid, but it's not a string. It means you should not use plain `%s` to print it. It is correct to use `printf("First rotor is: %.26s\n", rotor[0][0].order);` which limits the printing to the 26 characters allocated to the `order` member of the structure. Alternatively, you should allocate 27 characters to the `order` member of `struct rotor_wirings`, which allows the permutation of the alphabet to be null terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't leave room for the trailing null at the end of the `order` string. It should be

```
char order[27];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written on all 26 bytes, leaving no space for terminating `'\0'` char, hence, provoking [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). With **27 chars array**, you will get your desired output. [Live Example](http://ideone.com/DY8QZi)

```
struct rotor_wirings
{
    char order[27]; // Extra byte for terminating '\0'
    char notch[2];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a memory alignment issue and you haven't declared enough space for your order array to be null terminated, to fix this specific code:

```
char order[27];
```

in the struct would fix it, if you're curious as to why this happened though it is because the notch variable address is aligned right after and printf found the null termination then.

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Answer (score -1):

One way may be like this:

```
struct rotor_wirings rotor[10][10] =
{
    /* Commercial Enigma A, B */
    {
        { "DMTWSILRUYQNKFEJCAZBPGXOHVQ"},
        { "HQZGPJTMOBLNCIFDYAWVEUSRKXE" }
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain whether there's any significance to the spacing difference.  More seriously, you're trying to squeeze 28 characters into a `char[26]` array, which is not going to work, and you've not explained why you are ignoring the notch data field.